# How can Use VBA to add index match multiple results

Tags: vba

Is there any way, to use vba for finding and adding up index match methods for multiple results on one criteria.Below I do it, with Find method, but I cannot take all values that are repeating, because at the end I need to sum up them( adding up).;
It would be better if anyone could help to do all this with index match

```
Dim FoundCell As Range
Dim FirstFoundCellAddress As String
Set FoundCell = SearchedRangeObject.Find(What:=SearchedData, After:=SingleCellRangeObject, LookIn:=XlFindLookInConstant, LookAt:=XlLookAtConstant, SearchOrder:=XlSearchDirectionConstant, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=BooleanValue)
If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
    FirstFoundCellAddress = FoundCell.Address
    Do
        Statements
        Set FoundCell = SearchedRangeObject.FindNext(After:=FoundCell)
    Loop Until FoundCell.Address = FirstFoundCellAddress
End If
```

Comment: What is `Statements`?

Comment: Instead of Statement I wrote in my code below; but it does not give me what I want

Dim svalue() As Variant
For i = 1 To Ubound(svalue)
svalue(i) = Foundcell.Offset(,2).Value
Next i

Comment: What I want is to do it with index match. But with multiple results it seems impossible ..? Can anyone help with  index match multiple results to sum

Comment: No. I dont need them here. Something like ;
--> svalue(previous) + svalue(actual) <-- inside loop. Maybe I need to change Do loop for For Next. Because with index number I can easily calculate previous and next values

Comment: My problem is not being able to take all available values inside Do while loop inside an array. Is there any possibility? Or for this I have to use For Next loop. But then I guess I have to change all code